# How can I find all source files included in multiple bazel targets?

Tags: bazel

In my codebase it's often a mistake to include the same source file in multiple targets (`cc_binary`, `cc_library`, etc). I'd like to detect this.

I can do

```
bazel query labels(srcs, //target:name)
```

to get a list of sources for a single target. This is *enough* to figure out which sources are part of multiple targets, by doing this for every target and detecting which source files are in multiple targets. But I'd still need a query to get me a list of every target.

It would be a lot easier/cleaner if I could just query which targets a source file belongs to and see if it's a source of multiple targets. Is that possible?

Also, I have a *lot* of source files, optimalness of the query is a concern too.

Answer (score 2):

A few clarifying questions:

- With what frequency would you like to detect this kind of scenario? (i.e. Do you want this run as a test, or do you want to manually verify this?)
- Is it considered an error if two unrelated targets A and B both depend on file foo, even if A does not depend on B, nor does B depend on A?
- Is it insufficient to restrict src visibility to targets which are defined in the same package? For example, consider ensuring `foo/bar/src.c` is only visible to targets defined in `foo/bar/BUILD`, and then ensure that `foo/bar/BUILD` contains only one `cc_library` target.

Consider using [aspects](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/aspects.html) to obtain a list of all transitive source files of a given target.

If you're truly attached to using `bazel query`, you can get a comprehensive list of every target under your project by invoking, for example,

```
bazel query //...
```